# How to configure firewalld (or polarproxy) as reverse proxy for one domain

Tags: reverse-proxy

I want to configure firewalld (sorry no need additional secondary proxy as apache, nginx or squid,
I need configure redirect by firewalld or my existing reversy proxy). I have running reverse proxy polarproxy in machine 192.168.0.106 (192.168.0.1/24).

I want to redirect all inbound request to domain xxxxxx.com from proxy-machine to machine 192.168.0.102 (where working local clone xxxxxx.com, this site use not only port 80). Any other request to other domain need to going free to gateway of this network 192.168.0.1 and to inet.

What firewalld command I need? Or maybe config of polarproxy support this rules?

Answer (score 0):

Add a static host entry like this in 192.168.0.106's /etc/hosts to have PolarProxy treat "xxxxxx.com" as "192.168.0.102":

```
192.168.0.102    xxxxxx.com
```

Also, make sure to *not* use `--connect 192.168.0.102` when starting PolarProxy. It will otherwise connect *all* sessions to that IP.